# Feature used to work on v3.12 does not work in v3.30

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I have put 2 svelte REPLs here,

1. https://svelte.dev/repl/8449811b601449d6b0bd40cd1dd5b594?version=3.12.1
2. https://svelte.dev/repl/d83532b26811443f91633dcb3ed224b4?version=3.30.0

It implements a slide show. Both REPLs are exactly same code. (1) works but (2) does not work. Something that used to work on v3.12 does not work in v3.30. Any clues would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```html
<script>
  import Slide from './Slide.svelte';
  ...
</script>
...
{#each buffer as Slide}
  <Slide {Slide}/>
{/each}
...
```

The local `Slide` variable in the each loop is shadowing the `Slide` import, so Svelte is trying to create a component from the slide data, not the `Slide` component.

If you change your variable name, it comes back to life:

```html
<script>
  import Slide from './Slide.svelte';
  ...
</script>
...
{#each buffer as slide}
  <Slide Slide={slide}/>
{/each}
...
```

This seems like proper behaviour to me. Your problem probably appeared following a bug fix in Svelte.

Comment: Cool, it missed my eyes! Thanks.